# c code to split files

Tags: c, file-io

I have written a program to split files into multiple part in C.  The code below is what I've been using to split text files which work correctly but it isn't able to split `.mp3` files:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char fn[250], ch, nfn[250];
    long int size, n, k;
    int i;
    FILE *f, *ft; //file and temp file

    printf("enter the file you want to split with full path : ");
    scanf("%s", fn);
    printf("enter the number of parts you want to split the file : ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    f=fopen(fn, "rb");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open file");
        exit(0);
    }

    fseek(f, 0, 2);
    size = ftell(f);
    printf("the size of the file in bytes is : %ld\n", size);

    i = 1;
    k = size/n;
    rewind(f);
    sprintf(nfn, "%s.%d", fn, i);
    ft = fopen(nfn, "wb");
    while(1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if (ch==EOF)
            break;
        fputc(ch, ft);
        if (ftell(f)==(i*k))
        {
            i = i+1;
            fclose(ft);
            sprintf(nfn, "%s.%d", fn, i);
            ft=fopen(nfn, "wb");
        }
    }
}
```

It just creates one file with the name `test.mp3.1` and stoped

Comment: Unix already has a `split` command that does this.

Comment: Take care of your buffer sizes! Never use `scanf` to input arbitrary-length strings. It just doesn't work. And, if the string in `fn` has a length of 248 or longer, you overflow `nfn` two times with your `sprintf` calls (if the program hasn't crashed earlier).

Comment: @mafso so which function should i use??

Comment: Depends on what you are going to achieve—do you want to truncate the user input? Then you can use `scanf` with a length modifier or (what I prefer) use `fgets`. If you don't want user input to be truncated, use [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) or maybe write some similar function, if you are on a non-POSIX platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char ch;
```

needs to be

```
int ch;
```

You're currently using too small a type for `ch`, meaning that the first byte with value 0xff is being confused with EOF.

Comment: Actually, it should be `if (ftell(ft) == k)` (note the whitespace! :P)

Comment: Yes it can be. I had tried that previously but it still doesn't work on mp3 files.

Comment: @Harishkrupo There was a second problem with your code.  I've updated my answer to cover this.

Comment: by doesn't work i mean the process stops after the creation of one file. whatever the value of n is only one file is created with size much smaller than the main file

Comment: yes it works. Could you please explain why it didn't when char ch was used?

Comment: if (ftell(f)==i*k) will work because suppose the file has a size of 32 bytes and n=4 so k=8 so the if statement will be activated when ftell(f) returns 8,16,24,32 creating 4 parts

Comment: Assuming 32-bit ints, `EOF` will likely be `0xffffffff`.  This gets truncated to `0xff` when you convert it to `char`.  `0xff` (or 255) is a valid byte value for a binary file; when you encounter the first byte with this value, you'll confuse it with `EOF`